# SCINet: how does interactive learning work?

Tags: neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, time-series, prediction, feature-extraction

i'm having some trouble understanding how does the basic building block of a [SCINet](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.09305) works. In the paper the author describes the SCI-block with the following figure:

[image: SCI-Block]

In which $\phi$, $\theta$, $\eta$ and $\rho$ are convolutional filters with the following architecture:

[image: Convolutional filter structure]

All this is described with the equations below:
[image: Odd and even equations]

What I understood is that the splitted sequences go through a gated linear unit (GLU) in order to control what information is passed from the complementary sequence. This creates $F_{odd}^{s}$ and $F_{even}^{s}$ which now contain relevant features from their complementary sequence.

However, I can't seem to understand why these enhanced sequences are further projected onto two additional hidden states with filters $\rho$ and $\eta$ in order to substract or add them to their complementary sequence. Why is this step added?

If this is a common practice in neural networks i'd be glad to know it's name and if you could point me to some reference that would be great. Thanks in advance!